# Iphone audio alert when application is not running? Possible? How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is this possible to get an audio alert when application is not running...? If yes then how it is possible?
How to sync a code when application is not running?
Have heard about Push notification services.but is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local notifications to schedule audio alerts that will be displayed even if the application is not running. There are some limitations regarding what you can play and for how long.

You can read more about local notifications at [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

On a non-jailbroken iPhone, no, it's not possible.  Your application can be running audio in the background on the 3GS and iPhone 4 however, only if the application has been launched and then backgrounded.